# std::sort is not moving the elements of a vector

Tags: c++, copy, operator-overloading

The goal is simple, I have a `Rectangle` class with width, height, and area properties. I have made an operator overload for the `<` operator, as that is what the `std::sort` uses for it's comparisons.

Based on what I have found online so far, it seems that this problem often stems from something being wrong in the copy operator or constructor for a class.

Here is my copy constructor for the `Rectangle` class:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(const Rectangle & other)
{
     m_width = other.m_width;
     m_height = other.m_height;
     m_area = other.m_area;
 }
```

And here is my copy operator:

```
 Rectangle & Rectangle::operator=(const Rectangle & rhs)
 {
     if (this != &rhs)
     {
         m_width = rhs.m_width;
         m_height = rhs.m_height;
     }
     return *this;
}
```

Here is the `<` operator:

```
bool Rectangle::operator<(const Rectangle & rhs)
{
    return (m_area > rhs.m_area);
}
```

And finally, here is how I call the sort method, just in case:

```
// rects is a vector<Rectangle> with several rectangles in it
std::sort(rects.begin(), rects.end());
```

I think that I am doing everything correctly, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: You let the compiler implement copy construction and assignment for you. It is less likely to introduce trivial bugs.

Comment: Why don't you copy the area in your assignment operator?

Comment: Your problem can’t be reproduced from that snippets => no help

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison uses only the `m_area` - as [@Galik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3807729/galik) pointed out, you are *not* setting that in your "copy operator". So it is not initialized and "the same" for all assignment-constructed instances - hence no sorting.

Depending on how you create your sample data, they all have an *uninitialized* `m_area`.

Fix it like so:

```
 Rectangle & Rectangle::operator=(const Rectangle & rhs)
 {
     if (this != &rhs)
     {
         m_width = rhs.m_width;
         m_height = rhs.m_height;
         m_area = rhs.m_area;    // FIX 
     }
     return *this;
}
```

[@Juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661519/juanchopanza) pointed out that using the autogenerated implementations would handle this correctly on theire own, so if no pressuring circumstances lead to you implementing these yourself, remove both.

Comment: The real fix is most likely to *not* implement copy and assignment.

Comment: @juanchopanza agreed - or fix it